# HighCharts how to add live series data set to existing chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This HighChart script plots a point on the graph when the any time the mouse is clicked. My problem is I would like to add a second series of data to the chart . The data will be incoming data x.y coordinates from a mqtt source. Ive been trying to do this for a few days without success.

Can some one show me how this is done? I can't even get the series labels to show up. An example with random data would be great.

`position_array = [[100 * Math.random() , 100 * Math.random()] // fake x,y data`

Thanks

```
(document).ready(function(){ // encapsulate jQuery
console.log("hey click");
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
        events: {
            click: function (e) {
                // find the clicked values and the series
                var x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
                    y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value),
                    series = this.series[0];
                // Add it
                console.log('2:',Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value))
                var coord = String(x)+','+String(y)
                publish(coord,'pclks',2);
                series.addPoint([x, y]);  
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Click supplied data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Move Robot by clicking a point on the Graph'
    },
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        maxZoom: 60
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        maxZoom: 60,
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            point: {
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        console.log("hey load b");
                        if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                            this.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{name: "data0",
        data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]},
    }]
});             });
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem ?. Where is second series will start from ?. Every time you click it will create other series from your last point of previous series, or anything else ?

Comment: Yes of course. The chart is a catesian x/y  plane ... one series is the coordinates of the mouse clicks, the other  series are the x,y coordinates of the robot sent via mqtt.  There will only be two series ,mouse click coords and robot coords. The second series where start from what ever coordinates are sent from the robot. The mouse click coordinates are totally independent and will appear where ever a click is made.

Comment: Ok now things are looking a bit better. I added a  “render to” after the chart : and my position data started plotting!

Answer (score 0):

As your explain, I've just made this solution on codepen because jsfidde is currently down :[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/lamvux/pen/bGGLPOZ)

I used a simute new data at the end of code to show how 2 series is totally independent

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'scatter',

    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            // find the clicked values and the series
            var x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
                y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value),
                series = this.series;
            // Add new series if not
            if (series.length < 2) {
                this.addSeries({
                    name: 'clicked-series',
                    data: [
                        [x, y]
                    ]
                });
            } else { // add new point
                series[1].addPoint([x, y])
            }

            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'User supplied data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        maxZoom: 60
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        maxZoom: 60,
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            point: {

            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [20, 20],
            [30, 80]
        ]
    }]
});
// simulate robot post new data to chart
k = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    chart.series[0].addPoint([35 * (k++), Math.random() * 100])
}, 10000)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem I still face is , How do I get my external mqtt data ([robot_pos] )into the Highchart.chart function to access chart.series[0].addPoint ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define this series (can be an empty object):

```
        series: [{
            name: "data0",
            data: [
                [20, 20],
                [80, 80]
            ]
        }, {

        }]
```

Or you can add it using `chart.addSeries()` method.

And then you can easily add points to the new series like in this example: https://codepen.io/raf18seb/pen/mddXNMo?editors=1010

```
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    var x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
                        y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value),
                        firstSeries = this.series[0],
                        secondSeries = this.series[1];
                    firstSeries.addPoint([x, y]);
                    secondSeries.addPoint([Math.round(Math.random() * 100), Math.round(Math.random() * 100)]);
                }
            }
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thank you .I Im still missing this main issue ... Can you show how my incoming mqtt data can access secondSeries.addPoint ?

Comment: I have it now. I added  " renderTo: 'container' " after chart:{

Comment: Ok. Any other questions or I can close the ticket? ;)

Comment: Yes please close ...Thank you